# PHP regex url matching

Tags: php, regex

I have some example:

```
mysite.com/tag/HD+Wallpaper           //match
mysite.com/tag/HD+Wallpaper/          //match
mysite.com/tag/HD+Wallpaper?page=     //match
mysite.com/tag/HD+Wallpaper/?page=    //match
  
mysite.com/tag/HD+Wallpaper/sdadasdas    //not match
```

with "HD+Wallpaper" is a param

i try :

```
^tag/(.+?)(|\/|\?(.*?))$i
```

How can i fix it ? TY

Comment: Have you tried something like `/tag/([^/\?]+)/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try following regex

```
tag\/.*?(?=\/|\?|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nxkix6/2/)

Note:
In the demo, I added backslash \ to escape /

Comment: But i dont want "mysite.com/tag/HD+Wallpaper/sdadasdas" match . Can you fix it

Comment: I hope the following regex could help you. 
`tag\/.*?(?:(?=[\/\?\s])(?!\/\w+))`.
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nxkix6/3/)

Comment: Hi @KathyRj. If my answer is useful, could you please accept my answer? Please click check mark on the left my answer.

Comment: sr bro , i'm new bie . i don't  know it's important for you

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
tag\/([^\/]*?)(?=\/$|\/\?|\?|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uPi6yj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
tag/[^/\s]+(?:/(?:\?.*)?)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `tag/` Match literally (perhaps `/tag/` or `\btag` would be more specific)
- `[^/\s]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `/` or a whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `/(?:\?.*)?` Match `/` followed by an optional part to match `?` and the rest of the string
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WlVEGf/1)